# R - loglikelihood and optim with conditional copula

Tags: r

I'm having a speed problem with my codes and I'm trying to solve it. I would like to have your opinion/help on these problems I'm sorry if my english isn't as good as expected. :P.

I'm kind of new in R language and I am currently working with conditional copula. I'm using R studio to the the programming and the R version 2.15.3. I'm using the `<copula>` package and I'm trying to do some mle estimating.

First, I have a bivariate vector u = [u_1, u_2] of length n = 250. I have a function like this :

```
logl = function(u,x,xcentre)
{
   function(b){
      thetaList = thetax(xcentre,b)

      #Try 1
      #vectD = mapply(function(t1,t2, theta) (dCopula(c(t1,t2), frankCopula(theta), 
      #log = TRUE)), u[,1], u[,2], thetaList)
      #return (-1/n*sum(vectD))

      #Try 2
      vectD = 0
      for (i in 1:n)
      {
         vectD = vectD + dCopula(u[i,], frankCopula(thetaListe[i]), log = TRUE)
      }
      return (-1/n*(vectD))
   } 
}
```

(1) x is a vector of length n = 250 with data. xcentre is a scalar (x = 1 for example)

(2)thetax(xcentre,b) returns a list of parameter theta of length n = 250 and puts it in    thetalist

You can replace the function dCopula for a function f(u,v) where u = [u_1, u_2] and v is a scalar.

So what I'm trying to do is this:

b : vector of 2 parameters
logl (b) = -1/n * sum [ log( f(u,v) ] where the sum is for all (u_i, v_i)  1 <= i <= n

My first attempt was to use the ´mapply´function and a ´for´ for the second attempt. But, it seems that the mapply is just a more beautiful way to write a for, lol. I need something that will increase the speed of the computation of logl(b).

I also tried function "Vectorize" to dCopula but it didn't give me what I need